# How to import two component in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have created two component header and footer. now I have called header component directly called index.js file working fine. below working page attached header section
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LH5qb.png)

Now I want to import footer component to index.js file but error displayed, need same page in http://localhost:3000/ (i.e) first displayed Herder another Footer component what I missing could you please solve this issues please. I refer more reference struck two days this concept.

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';

     import Header from './header'
    import Footer from './footer'
     function Index({posts}) {
       return (
         <>
             <Header posts={posts}/>
             <Footer/> 
         </>
       )
     }
    
    export async function getServerSideProps() {
            const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            const posts = await res.json()
    
            return {
              props: {
                posts
              },
            }
          }
    
    export default Index;
```

Header.js

```
function Header(props) {
  return (
    <div Style="background: #f2e7d7;padding: 20px; border: 1px solid #eeca97;border-radius: 10px;">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>
       {props.posts.map((post) =>(
         <>
          <span>{post.name}</span><span>/</span>
          </>
        ))}
    </p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Footer.js

```
import React from 'react';
 import FooterApi from './footerApi'
 function Footer({postTitle}) {
   return (
     <>
         <FooterApi postTitle={postTitle}/>
     </>
   )
 }

export async function getServerSideProps() {
        const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        const postTitle = await res.json()

        return {
          props: {
            postTitle
          },
        }
      }

export default Footer;
```

footerApi.js

```
function FooterApi(props) {
    return (
      <div Style="background: #f2e7d7;padding: 20px; border: 1px solid #eeca97;border-radius: 10px;">
      <h1>Footer</h1>
      <p>
         {props.postTitle.map((post) =>(
           <>
            <span>{post.title}</span>
            </>
          ))}
      </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
  
  export default FooterApi
```

Comment: *but error displayed* - this isn't very helpful. Please include what exactly the error is that's being displayed.

Comment: What is `postTitle` supposed to be? It appears to be undefined, but you're trying to map over it as if its an array

Comment: Yes postTitle  is undefined, I need display this page http://localhost:3000/ first Header and Footer component.

Comment: You can't link to a port local to your machine... it will only ever work for you

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're calling `getServerSideProps()` inside of a component and not a page.

To fix this you can fetch your data (postTitle) inside `index.js` `getServerSideProps()` and then pass it to the footer like you did to the Header

You index.js should look something like this (I just replaced your code)

```js
import React from 'react';

import Header from './header';
import Footer from './footer';
function Index({ posts, postTitle }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Header posts={posts} />
      <Footer postTitle={postTitle} />
    </>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  const posts = await res.json();
  const resFooter = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
  const postTitle = await resFooter.json();
  return {
    props: {
      posts,
      postTitle,
    },
  };
}

export default Index;
```

and your footer.js

```js
import React from 'react';
 import FooterApi from './footerApi'
 function Footer(props) {
   return (
     <>
         <FooterApi postTitle={props.postTitle}/>
     </>
   )
 }

export default Footer;
```

Comment: Can you please correction in my code please.  I refer more reference could not solve this issue please help me

Comment: Is possible to call two time in getServerSideProps inside of index.js

Comment: @karthik I updated the answer with the code

Comment: thanks for your help this line <Footer posts={postTitle} /> error displayed ReferenceError: postTitle is not defined

Comment: change <Footer posts={postTitle} /> to <Footer postTitle={postTitle} />. I'll update the code

Comment: Your great Mohamed, I forgot your help thanks Lot Awesome,